# python and selenium code was working one hour ago but stopped working now

Tags: python, html, selenium, button, xpath

Dear community member,

So i was locating the next button in google search on the bottom right, here is the HTML code:

```
<td aria-level="3" class="d6cvqb" role="heading"><a href="/search? q=site:linkedin.com/in/+AND+%22Kleiner+Perkins%22+AND+%22profile%22&amp;biw=801&amp;bih=661&amp;sxsrf=AL eKk015vcO0GNGs89AY8isGkfsRmY5fEw:1619014736075&amp;ei=UDSAYLCMBM- zsAfljLiQBQ&amp;start=30&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiw9Orxw4_wAhXPGewKHWUGDlI4FBDw0wN6BAgBEEk"
id="pnnext" style="text-align:left">
<span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.webp) no-repeat;background- 
position:-96px 0;width:71px"></span><span style="display:block;margin-left:53px">Next</span></a></td>
```

I used the following code in python to locate the button and click it:

```
next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']") 
next_button.click()
```

One hour ago everthing was working and i was kinda happy but now it cannot locate the button, i appreciate your time and help!

Edit: i printed out the google page_source and i noticed that somehow i got detected, is there a way to resolve?

Comment: See what's in `driver.page_source` and check if the HTML is still what you expect. Perhaps Google search determined you were doing web scraping and gave you a different page.

Comment: How to resolve being detected?

Comment: Try adding random sleeps (`time.sleep(...)`) in hopes that Google thinks you're a person doing the clicking and not some bot. There's a thread here on SO that discusses anti-detection strategies but I am too busy to go search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need till the button is clickable.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='pnnext']")))
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']")
elem.click()
```

**Option 2**

Try using this locator with wait:

```
//a[@id='pnnext' and contains(@href, '/search')]
```

Or,

```
//a[@id='pnnext' and contains(@href, '/search')]/span[1]
```

Comment: I just ran the code and it's not working, timeout

Comment: I think it's not a button problem anymore but seeing the page_source i noticed that google says in the page "unusual trafic detected. Don't know how to resolve this new problem

Comment: I think that you will need for some time after which you will be allowed to run your script again. Add some waits to it, so your browser behaviour would be human-like.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following. If you have an ID use that instead of X-path as it is the fastest. As well as implicit wait.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5) 
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=test')
google_next = driver.find_element(By.ID, "pnnext")
google_next.click()
```

Comment: I think it's not a button problem anymore but seeing the page_source i noticed that google says in the page "unusual trafic detected. Don't know how to resolve this new problem

Comment: https://piprogramming.org/articles/How-to-make-Selenium-undetectable-and-stealth--7-Ways-to-hide-your-Bot-Automation-from-Detection-0000000017.html

Comment: See the above link for how to hide automation detection, could be the issue.